# AdaBoost Weight Updating for Misclassified Points

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/adaboost4.pdf

I was reading this paper and came across the question showed in the second image. However, in the first image provided in a book on Machine Learning, the author shows that there is no updated needed to the hits and you can simply just increase the weights of misses. I am wondering if that is the answer or if it is more nuanced? How would I update misclassified points when not updating the weights of hits?

[image]
[image]